# Two packages with the same import name conflicting

Tags: python, django, python-packaging, infusionsoft

I am interacting with the InfusionSoft API in a Django project that I am working on.  I would like to use both infusionsoft-client package and infusionsoft-python.

However, they both require

```
import infusionsoft
```

so now I am getting error messages regarding infusionsoft-client attributes that are already working.

How can I set these up so that they do not conflict?

Comment: rename one of them. If code is in file then rename file, if code is in folder then rename folder.

Comment: You can use alias for any one of the import. Like import infusionsoft as isoft

Comment: but if they are both called infusionsoft how will is know which one to import as isoft?